# how to send variable from controller to model function in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to send variable `$typeid` to function categories to use it in query is there a way Knowing that when I try to use new instance of class in my controller like that:

```
 $cat= new Main_category();
 $categories  = $cat->categories()->get();
```

it returns empty array

the following code is working well when I manually add the typeid inside the model function I want to have it as a variable sent from controller

controller:

```
$categories  = Main_category::with('categories')->get();
```

Model

```
public  function categories()//($typeid) 
{  

     $query = $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'main_cat_id')
              ->join('category_type','category_type.cat_id','=', 'categories.cat_id')                                                   
              ->join('main_categories','main_categories.main_cat_id','=', 'categories.main_cat_id')                                                           
              ->where('category_type.type_id', '1');  // I want to use $typeid here


     return  $query;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you can pass your variable in eloquent relationship methods by using `with` method or not. But you can add a where clause in controller.

```
Main_category::with(['categories' => function($query) use($typeid) {
    $query->where('category_type.type_id', $typeid);
}])->get();
```

Or you can create a query scope for model too.

in Model

```
public function scopeWithCategories($query, $typeid) {
    return $query->with(['categories' => function($query) use($typeid) {
        $query->where('category_type.type_id', $typeid);
    }]);
}
```

and finally in Controller

```
Main_category::withCategories($typeid)->get();
```